# MVC4 Html.DropDownListFor is not selecting specified value

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html.dropdownlistfor, selectedvalue

I have the following classes:

```
public class PreviewImage_Edit
{
    ...
    public List<GridDetail_Edit> GridDetails { get; set; }
    public SelectList GridDetailTypesList { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class GridDetail_Edit
{
    ...
    public int GridDetailTypeId { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And, I have a partial view that expects a model of type PreviewImage_Edit, which has the following block of code:

```
@model PreviewImage_Edit
...
@if (Model.GridDetails != null)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.GridDetails.Count(); i++)
    {
        ...
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GridDetails[i].GridDetailTypeId, Model.GridDetailTypesList)
        ...
    }
}
```

I am properly creating the SelectList in GridDetail_Edit and the dropdown is populating as expected.  Below is the markup that is generated for the first GridDetails object:

```
<select data-val="true" data-val-number="The field GridDetailTypeId must be a number." data-val-required="The GridDetailTypeId field is required." id="GridDetails_0__GridDetailTypeId" name="GridDetails[0].GridDetailTypeId">
    <option value="1">Top</option>
    <option value="2">Bottom</option>
</select>
```

I've verified that the selected choice is properly saved in the database (even when the selected option isn't the first/default option in the dropdown) when the Save button is clicked.  However, when I go back to re-edit, the selected option continues to be the first option in the dropdown.

I stepped through the code and verified that the data is properly retrieved from the database.  I've even gone so far as converting the **Html.DropDownListFor** to **Html.EditorFor** and confirmed that the value stored in the database is making it to the view as expected.

I've used **Html.DropDownListFor** when the property associated with it was an integer value but never when it's an integer value that's part of a collection of objects.  I would be apprehensive about what I've done so far, but everything appears to be working with this one key issue.

So far, I've tried moving the SelectList in PreviewImage_Edit into GridDetail_Edit and initializing them separately where I've programmatically set the "Selected" value for the appropriate SelectedListItem.  That didn't work... same result.

Has anyone come across this issue?  Any suggestions on the best way to resolve this?

---

**Update**

Below is the snippet of code that populates GridDetailTypesList

```
var gridDetailTypes = _db.GridDetailTypes.OrderBy(g => g.DisplayOrder).ToList();
return new SelectList(gridDetailTypes, "GridDetailTypeId", "Name");
```

It's pretty straightforward.  The second parameter of the SelectList constructor represents the field whose values should be used in the "value" attribute.  I don't believe the issue is related to the fact that the value field is an integer as I have similar code on the same page and that dropdown is functioning properly.  The only difference is that my "problem" dropdowns are within a collection of my ViewModel.

Comment: Can you add the snippet of code where you insert items into GridDetailsTypeList? It may have something to do with that (the value of GridDetailTypeId being an int, while the SelectListItems value being strings)

Answer (score 0):

The only time I've seen messages on a dropdown about "must be a number" was when I screwed up and the (numeric) value of the OPTIONs were being padded with spaces when I loaded them from a database.  This doesn't appear to be your problem (and your example specifically shows no padding) but I would definitely want to look at the value of GridDetails[0].GridDetailTypeId to make sure it was of the correct type/value.

Wish I could add this as a comment rather than an answer - but my rep isn't high enough yet...

Answer (score 0):

The only way it works for me is when my List is a simple `IEnumerable<string>`, or when I pass the same property of my custom object for both the DataText as the DataValue. As follows:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TypeOfFilter, new SelectList(Model.Filters, "DataText", "DataText")
```

where TypeOfFilter is an enum and Model.Filters is a `List<MySelectItemModel>`.
That way you can see in the generated HTML that the right option is selected.